# nodejs serialport detect change in cts pin on Windows

Tags: node.js, serial-port

With NodeJS I would like to listen to changes on the CTS pin. The system is getting an external signal on the CTS pin. Most of the time the signal is on/high. I need to detect changes from low to high and high to low.

There is a package [serialport](https://serialport.io/) and I've tried several settings in the `options` for creating a new `SerialPort` instance in node with the package (`rtscts/xon/xoff` to `true/false`). However, there is no 'listen' callback and I'm stuck how to do this? Searched the docs but can't find how to do this (if it is even possible).

Is it possible to detect changes on the CTS pin in NodeJS and if so how?

Comment: https://serialport.io/docs/guide-usage#reading-data did you check this?

Comment: Since it is called `get (): Promise <Flags>` [Abstract Binding](https://serialport.io/docs/api-binding-abstract), it seems that the status can be known, so why not check it cyclically by timer processing etc.?

Comment: Thanks, didn't read the docs properly. That will do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Answer provided by @Aritra Chakraborty and @kunif